# Wheatstone bridge analysis

Tags: homework, sampling, wheatstone-bridge, instrumentation, data-acquisition

**Hello,
I am facing issues in calculating few parameters for the following information. I am new to this concept of strain gauge, wheatstone bridge, and data acquisition system**

Four resistive strain gauges are used to measure vertical load F applied to a cantilever-beam structure (Figure 1). The dimensions for the cantilever beam are l = 30 cm, t = 1 cm, and w = 10 cm. The Young’s modulus of the beam material is E = 207 GPa. The distance between the center of the strain gauges and the root of the beam is x = 10 cm.

A Wheatstone bridge is used to convert the resistance changes in the strain gauges to a voltage signal. The strain gauges are arranged in a 4-active arm, full-bridge configuration (Figure 2).  The excitation voltage is 10 V. The gauge factor of the strain gauges is 2.0.

[image]

[image]

A. Place the strain gauges on the Wheatstone bridge by numbering the four arms in Figure 2 properly.
B. Does your placement of the strain gauges allow temperature compensation? Why?
C. If the force applied to the beam is F = 1000 N, what signal level is expected from the output of the bridge?
D. What would be the expected output voltage level if the excitation voltage is raised to 20 V? Would this increase in excitation voltage cause any problems? Explain.

**Here, in part C and D how do I calculate the direct relationship between the force applied and the output voltage across the wheatstone bridge? Is there a direct formula to do so?**

Secondly, The signal from the Wheatstone bridge is now directly sent to a differential channel of a data acquisition system (DAS). The bi-polar input mode and a range of 0-100 mV were selected for the channel.

A. It was found that, for a steady force load, the voltage level of measured signal tends to shift greatly. What could be the cause of this problem?
B. If the “throughput” of the DAS is 333 kHz, what is the highest possible sampling frequency one can achieve for the signal from the bridge? Assume this is the only analog signal to be handles by the DAS.
C.  What is the “resolution” for the measured voltage signal from the Wheatstone bridge?
D.  What is the “resolution” for the measured force F?
E.  If the load to be measured is a vibrating force at a frequency of 20 kHz, what sampling frequency would you suggest? Why?

**Here, in part C and D, how does one find resolution of the measured voltage signal from the wheatstone bridge and the measured force applied? Does the range of of 0-100 mV given has to do something with this?**

Comment: Welcome to the group. We will offer you help but we won't do your raw coursework for you. Please review the help information (see the ? in the top-right) starting with the tour. Select one part of your question you'd like to focus on, tell us what you've tried and where you got stuck.  This group is not a substitute for attending your lectures or reading your notes and textbook.

Comment: @GrahamNye Thanks for your prompt response. In the first part, I am stuck in part c and d specifically. If I will be able to get the equations which relate the force and resistance and in turn the voltage, then I will be able to tackle the question. 
For the second part, I am unable to understand how to find the resolution parameter. This is again part c and d but for the second half.

Comment: Comments are temporary and can be deleted so you need to add this additional information into your question, rather than adding it in a comment. You also have two lots of C & D so you need to make clear if you are referring to the first or second set. Don't make people have to guess.

Comment: @GrahamNye, Thanks for the inputs. I have made required changes where I have asked in bold about my specific problems that I am facing. Also, I have given a brief summary at the start. Again, thanks for your inputs and I am open to any more suggestions.

Comment: How are gauges 1 to 4 electrically arranged?

Comment: @Andyaka, The top left is R3, bottom left is R4. The top right is R1 and the bottom right is R2. I was trying to see if I can attach a picture but I am not able to do so.